# jQuery sort two same list on sorting one another also sort in same order

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sorting

i have to sort two same ul
having same class and same li element
if user perform sorting on one ul then same operation should perform 
on the other ul

```
code:

<ul class="sort">
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
</ul>


<ul class="sort">
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
</ul>
```

list are clone i.e. both are same if i perform operation of jquery
sorting in one then it should sort both of the list in same order in same time.

i am using jquery ui for this:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>



 <script>
 $(function() {
 $( ".sort").sortable().disableSelection();
 });
 </script>
```

what should be the changes in

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
 $( ".sort").sortable().disableSelection();
 });
 </script>
```

segment to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hacky but in the `update` event function you and completely refill the other HTML with the sorted one content.

Code:

```
 $(function () {
     $(".sortable").sortable({
         update: function (event, ui) {
             $(".sortable").not($(this)).html($(this).html());
         }
     }).disableSelection();
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/LNH3h/

### UPDATE

Founded a better solution, instead of recreate the list all switched the elements according to the moved element.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).data("elPos", ui.item.index());
        },
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var origPos = $(this).data("elPos");
            $(".sortable").not($(this)).each(function (i, e) {
                if (origPos > ui.item.index()) {
                    $(this).children("li:eq(" + origPos + ")").insertBefore($(this).children("li:eq(" + ui.item.index() + ")"));
                } else {
                    $(this).children("li:eq(" + origPos + ")").insertAfter($(this).children("li:eq(" + ui.item.index() + ")"));
                }
            })
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/LNH3h/5/

Comment: @downvoter give the reason why...or a better solution instead

Comment: this method is not working. see your updated fiddle .
http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/LNH3h/2/

Comment: it's not sorting element

Comment: yes this works but here is a problem it's replacing "li" class i.e if <li class="green"> and other list <li class="blue"> then after sorting all list li class are same .

Comment: @user3706494 that was not a requirement in the fisrt question/code; I'll change the code accordingly

Comment: yes your code working according to question cause other condition is not mention in the question but if i have more then 2 list i.e if i have 10 list with same class but it's li having different attribute such as id,class,data-attribute then all li should have their own id or class attribute make it if you can.

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward this update is definitely better approach thanks to update.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<ul class="sort1">
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
</ul>


<ul class="sort2">
<li>a</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>d</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sort2">
<li>a</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>d</li>
</ul> 


 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".sort1").sortable();
     $(".sort1").disableSelection();
    $(".sort2").val($(".sort1").val());

})
 </script>
```

Comment: this is not working only one list is sorting at a time i want to sort both at same time.